# Do polynomials in two variables always factor in linear terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider a polynomial of one variable over $\Bbb C$:
$$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n,\quad a_i\in\Bbb C.$$
We know from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that there exists $c,\alpha_i\in\Bbb C$ such that
$$p(x)=c(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n),$$
i.e. we can factor $p$ in *linear terms*.

Now, what about polynomials $p(x,y)$ in two variables?

> Is it still true that we can factor $p(x,y)$ in linear terms? I.e. can we always write
>   $$p(x,y)=c(\alpha_1x+\beta_1y+\gamma_1)\cdots(\alpha_nx+\beta_ny+\gamma_n)$$
>   for some $c,\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i\in\Bbb C$?

Comment: If that were true, every two variable polynomial would have its zero set as a union of lines,

Comment: Note the above comment is not quite right, since one may be working over the complex numbers.

Comment: @coffeemath: Your first comment is excellent and quite, strictly, absolutely, completely, totally valid. Especially over $\mathbb C$ :-)

Answer (score 24):

Let me add to Martin's perfect answer that a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y)$ (=sum of monomials of the same degree) in **two** variables  **does** factor into linear homogeneous factors in an essentially unique way, that is up to permutations of the factors and multiplication of the factors by constants. More explicitly:  $$f(x,y) =\sum_{i+j=d} a_{ij}x^iy^j=\prod _{k=1}^d(u_ix+v_iy)$$ However this is no longer true if the number of variables is $\geq 3$.
For example the polynomial $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is irreducible i.e. has no non-trivial factorization.

Finally note that **if** a homogeneous polynomial has a factorization, then  the factors must be homogeneous too. For example :   $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x+wy+w^2z)(x+w^2y+wz)                      $$ (where $w=e^{2i\pi/3} $)

**Edit**
By request of a great contributor to this site, here is an explanation of why a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y)$ **in two variables over an algebraically closed field**  can be factored into linear  polynomials:
Just write  $$f(x,y)=\sum _{i=0}^da_{i}x^iy^{d-i}=y^d\sum _{i=0}^da_i(\frac xy)^i=y^d\prod_{i=1}^d (u_i(\frac xy)+v_i)=\prod_{i=1}^d (u_ix+v_iy)$$ The penultimate equality results from  the factorization  of a univariate polynomial into degree one factors.
[The calculation above is true only if $a_d\neq0$, i.e. if $f$ is not divisible by $y$.
If $f$ *is*  divisible by $y$, one must very slightly modify the above but $f$ is still a product of linear factors, some of them now being equal to $y$. For example  $x^2y^2+y^4=y^2(x+iy)(x-iy)$ ]

Comment: Dear @Georges, maybe you want to explain why the homogeneous polynomials of degree $\ge2$ in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ are reducible (if I've understood correctly what you said).

Comment: Dear @user26857: yes you have (of course!) perfectly understood what I meant. I have added an edit with the requested explanation.

Comment: Thanks. (+1) Meanwhile I've found a topic about this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891109/factoring-homogeneous-polynomials-in-two-variables

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer (+1). For future readers: The calculation in the edit can be summarized as *dehomogenize the homogeneous polynomial $f$ and then use that $f$ is defined over an algebraically closed field.* Finally, the slight modification needed in case that $y$ divides $f$ mentioned in the edit amounts to writing $f=y^k \cdot g$ where $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $g$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d-k$ which is not divisible by $y$. One can then perform the above calculation for $g$.

Answer (score 22):

My candidate to fail is $xy+1$. If this is the product of linear terms, we can have at most two of degree one. So
$$
xy+1=(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f).
$$
We need $ad=be=0$, to avoid the squares. If $a=0$, then  $b\ne0$ and so $e=0$. We have
$$
xy+1=bdxy+bfy+cdx+cf.
$$
Then $ cf=1$, $bf=cd=0$. So $b=d=0$, making the equality impossible. The other case is similar.

Comment: Right. So would the proper generalization be that $p(x,y)$ can be factored in terms of degree 1? i.e. $a+bx+cy+dxy$?

Comment: Can we say something at all about the factorization of $p(x,y)$?

Comment: @123 we can say the factorization into irreducibles is unique, but even over an algebraically  closed field there are irreducible polynomials of any degree with more than one variable.

Answer (score 7):

To show that this is not the case, look at $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$, which is true all along the unit circle, if your idea was true that we could factor down to "individual zero points", we would need to have infinite number of factors since there are infinitude of points on the unit circle. Also linear terms would not be possible, since the unit circle is curved and not a set of lines.