# Factorization of a multivariate degree 2 homogeneous polynomial into two linear terms

Tags: polynomials

I am looking to solve the following problem regarding polynomials:

Suppose that all of the roots $(r_1, r_2, r_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ of a linear form $\sum_{k=1}^3 g_k x_k$ are roots of a quadratic form $\sum_{i,j=1}^3 b_{ij}x_ix_j$. How do you show that exists another linear form $\sum_{l=1}^3 h_l x_l$ such that $$ \sum_{i,j=1}^3 b_{ij}x_ix_j = \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 g_k x_k \right) \left( \sum_{l=1}^3 h_l x_l \right). $$

Could someone give me some advice/help?

I know that if the forms were in two variables, it would be "trivial". From this post [Do polynomials in two variables always factor in linear terms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463537/do-polynomials-in-two-variables-always-factor-in-linear-terms/1463681), when there are more than two terms, it gets harder.

Comment: I don't see why $x_1, x_2,$ and $x_3$ are roots of $g_1x_1 + g_2x_2 + g_3 x_3$; indeed, I don't even know whether the $x_i$ are meant to be constants or indeterminates. Can you clarify, perhaps giving names to some functions or something?

Comment: @JohnHughes we suppose that they are roots of a multivariate polynomial. What do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change coordinates so that the vector $g = (g_1, g_2, g_3)$ is $(1, 0, 0)$.

Now we have a quadratic $B(x) = \sum b_{ij} x_i x_j$ that's zero on the whole $x_1$-axis. The first Lemma in Chapter 3 of Samuel's *Projective Geometry* says (with some parts omitted)

**Lemma**: let $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a homogeneous quadratic polynomial over a field $K$. Then

(a)  [...]

(c) if $P(0, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ for every $a = (a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in K^{n-1}$, then $P$ is a multiple of $x_1$.

---

Applying that to our situation, we see that $B(x) = x_1 H(x)$, where $H$ is necessarily homogeneous of degree $1$, i.e., a linear form, and we're done.

The proof Samuel gives is this:

Write $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = c_1 x_1^2 + x_1 P_1(x_2, \ldots, x_n) + P_2(x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, where $P_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$. Now evaluating this at $(0, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ gives $0 = 0  + 0 P_1(a_2, \ldots, a_n) + P_2(a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, hence the homogeneous quadratic polynomial $P_2$ is zero. But then 
\begin{align}
P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) 
&= c_1 x_1^2 + x_1 P_1(x_2, \ldots, x_n) + P_2(x_2, \ldots, x_n)\\
&= c_1 x_1^2 + x_1 P_1(x_2, \ldots, x_n) + 0\\
&= x_1 \left( c_1 x_1 + P_1(x_2, \ldots, x_n)\right).
\end{align}

[I've put words in Samuel's mouth here; he basically says "write $P$ this way; then it's clear that $P_2$ is zero."]

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot, this is perfect!

Comment: Thank Pierre Samuel. I was just the transcriber. :)

Comment: His book is extremely pretentious at times, but also extremely useful at times...